# crystal report charts line weight

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am trying to increase the line weight of my line chart in crystal report,
is that doable , yes or no ?? and if yes please provide me with the steps needed to perform such a thing, **even through code I am using asp.net C#** .

Regards,

Baher.

Comment: If you are using crystal report for visual studio which is free then its limitation, you have to purchase license version. refer  https://answers.sap.com/questions/622628/increase-thickness-of-line.html

Answer (score 0):

In Design mode right click the line on the chart and select `Format Connector Line`  You can then select the Thickness of the line from the drop down.

EDIT:

In `Design` mode of Crystal Reports

[image: Crystal Reports - Format Connector Line]

Comment: First the line on the chart is not selectable, second when i right click the chart the context menu which appears contains the following items:
1- Format Object
2- Chart Exprt
3- Chart Options

Comment: @baharanji - I have updated my answer. Are you in Design Mode?

Comment: I am using crystal reports 8 , and i cannot find that option

Comment: @Bahanranji - Hmm I don't have Crystal Reports 8 so I can't help I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal 8.5 (which I think was identical to Crystal 8 in this regard, although we moved from 8 to 8.5 pretty quickly) you can only get at that option via the Chart Analyzer, which only appears in Preview mode. Once in Preview Mode, right-click on the Chart, select Chart Analyzer, and then you can tinker with all the layout, line thickness, etc.

The ability to do this directly from Design Mode was only added in Crystal 9.